I tried both ng serve and ionic serve commands, running my ionic Angular project, I am facing the error "ionic :The term 'ionic' is not recognised
ionic serve error :
ng serve error: 
PS E:\sss> ng serve
Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace.
PS E:\sss> ionic serve
ionic : The term 'ionic' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At line:1 char:1

ionic serve

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ionic:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException





This is how my folder structure looks like
enter image description here
Can anyone help me in solving this issue
I am trying to run my angular ionic project, I used both "ng serve" & "ionic serve" commands to run the project, still I am unable to run the project in my local server. Angular version in my system is 17, ionic version 7.2.0, and node v20.15.0
Angular CLI: 17.2.2
Node: 20.15.0
Package Manager: npm 10.8.2
OS: win32 x64
How can to solve this error

You have to run the commands at the root of your project ( folder where package.json is located ).
You get this error when you have not installed angular globally. Try installing it globally.
npm i @angular/cli@17.2.2 -g 

Do the same for ionic.

If the above does not work out, try running the commands locally using npx
npx ng serve

